# Reading a binary file causes error "formatted I/O to unit open for unformatted transfers"

Tags: fortran, binaryfiles, intel-fortran

I'm trying to open a.binary file in Fortran. In Visual Studio 2010 it looks like this (left is the line number, middle is hexadecimal and the right seems to be the ASCII representation of each byte of hex.

[Screenshot of the binary file content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPlhL.png)

I think I know how to decipher the hex (every 4 bytes or so is some information), I can read it visually and such and so I know what I want to do once I get a program to read it in, but I'm having trouble doing just that.

I've tried several different options, such as:

```
open(123, file=inputname,status='old', iostat=ierr,form='unformatted',err=90, access='stream')
read(123,*), line

forrtl: severe (257): formatted I/O to unit open for unformatted transfers, unit 123
----
! Trying some formatting and also now form='formatted' !
open(123, file=inputname, status='old', iostat=ierr, form='formatted',err=90,access='stream')
read(123,*), line

100 format (4(Z4.8))

forrtl: severe (64): input conversion error, unit 123
----
! formatted and removed the output formatting !
open(123, file=inputname, status='old', iostat=ierr, form='formatted',err=90,access='stream')
read(123,*), line

forrtl: severe (59): list-directed I/O syntax error, unit 123
----
```

And so on, I've tried several other combinations. Am I missing something?

(Note: all errors are triggered on the `READ` command)

Comment: What if you get rid of the comma before `line` on the read statement?

Comment: Tried it, doesn't change anything.

Comment: the error is because you have opened "unformatted" as you should, then supply a format ("*") on the read.  Try 'read(123)line'. `line` must be declared of the correct type corresponding the the data in the file of course

Comment: Even where there is a syntax error reported?

Comment: Yeah, I have tried before without the '*' but then it'll just print some of the unprintable characters and the ASCII equivalent of the binary. I tried a binary reading function I had that worked before on other binary files but this just spit out random numbers and ASCII, I'm pretty sure I've set the right variables (integers).

Answer (score 0):

That looks kinda like the output of DEBUG.EXE where the first entry is the hex address of the first byte, then the values of the next 16 bytes in hex, then the ASCII representation with unprintable characters represented by periods. It's a pity you didn't post the exact file so we have to guess from the picture, but a wrote a trial program with a format that reads a line of my best guess as the to nature of the file in question.

```
program readit
   use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV
   implicit none
   integer(INT32) number
   integer(INT8) data(16)
   character(16) string
   integer i
   integer iunit
   open(newunit=iunit,file='sample.txt',status='old')
   do i = 1, 1000000
      read(iunit,'(Z8,2(1x,8(1x,Z2)),2x,A16)',end=10) number,data,string
      write(*,'(*(g0:1x))') number,data,string
   end do
10 continue
end program readit
```

**EDIT**: I misinterpreted what was represented in your posted image. All the more reason to have posted the actual file. If every 4 bytes of the file contents is a meaningful input, you could just read it in stream format:

```
program readstream
   use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV
   implicit none
   integer(INT32) stuff
   integer iunit
   open(newunit=iunit,file='sample.txt',status='old',access='stream')
   do
      read(iunit,end=10) stuff
      write(*,'(Z8.8)') stuff
   end do
10 continue
end program readstream
```

Comment: This seems to be something that works, thanks! Why do you use the ISO_FORTRAN_ENV and call the integer sizes like that? I'm just trying to figure out why my code won't work, it is rather similar (examples in the main post, I did also try the stream approach). And how might I jump some number of bytes ahead or behind, or to a specific point, like with direct-access? I suppose an INQUIRE statement might be the way to go about it?

Comment: I knew what sizes of integers I wanted so I used the KINDs from ISO_FORTRAN_ENV to get them. Your code didn't work because you were using formatted READ on a file opened for unformatted form. To jump around in a file, first use `INQUIRE(IOLENGTH=some_var) stuff` to figure out how big a file storage unit is, then `INQUIRE(iunit,POS=another_var)`to get the current position in file storage units in the file, and then you can use `READ(iunit,POS=yet_another_var) more_stuff` to read from an arbitrary position, specified in file storage units, in the file.

Comment: Sorry, I meant more like "Is there a difference between that and just using INTEGER*4?" which is what I was using.

Thanks, I managed to figure the jumping around, I've used it before. However, in the past I've only done it with a single record length, can this be changed within the same file call? e.g. using two different lengths, sometimes 4 bytes maybe, sometimes 8? And what do you mean formatted READ? As in my OP, I had tried STREAM and UNFORMATTED before, and all the other combinations of SEQUENTIAL/DIRECT, etc., there are about 6 options between the 3.